# Cannot import user-defined module

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-5.0

I have some PowerShell functions and I want to import them into my server 2008 R2 via command `Import-Module`. So I created a psd1 file and in psm1 I use: `Export-ModuleMember -Function "*-*" -Alias *`.

However when I execute command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module Myloader -DisableNameChecking -Verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Tools\Myloader.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Tools\Myloader.psm1'.
```

I expect it should import my functions but it does not and there is no errors shown up. Then I execute `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, my function is listed out but there is no information about `ExportedCommands`

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     3.0        MyLoader
Script     3.0        MyLoader
```

But when I run it on my local machine it is OK. Have anyone faced with this issue before?

This issue happens on Windows Server 2008 R2, PowerShell 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

When using a [module manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you do the exports inside the .psd1 file. Remove the `Export-ModuleMember` statement from your .psm1 file and make sure the .psd1 file contains the following lines:

```
ModuleToProcess   = 'MyLoader.psm1'
FunctionsToExport = '*-*'
AliasesToExport   = '*'
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Ansgar. I did the same with your suggestion but there is nothing change.

Comment: @PhongVo Then you need to show the content of both your psm1 and psd1 file. Please edit your question to include that information.